# Accessing shipping cost in Magento's cart and/or checkout

Tags: php, magento, cart

Please note, this question is regarding the shipping cost, not price.  There is an important difference, i.e. what $$ charge the shipping method incurs for the store owner, as opposed to what is $$ charge is paid by the customer.

The `shipping_tablerate` database table includes a `cost` field, which is populated in the `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate` object during the `collectRates` method.  However, that field is not accessible anywhere else in the stack, e.g. from a quote's address.

I need to access that value on the cart page, and I can't find anyway to achieve it, other than to instantiate a `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request` object to pass into `collectRates()`.  That seems unnecessarily inefficient given that the data is already loaded from the table and should be accessible.

I have tried Observing the `<shipping_carrier_tablerate_load/>` event, but it seems that the `_load` event is not thrown for that model.

I have also tried accessing the rate from the quote:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$rate = $address->getShippingRateByCode($code ='tablerate_bestway');
```

I can see the calculated `price`, however `cost` is not present in that model.

At this stage, I'm running out of ideas.  Any suggestions gratefully received!

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, try not to worry too much about performance until you see an actual bottleneck somewhere.  Have faith in the multitude of caching systems. Put more cynically, Magento's already a bit of a SQL beast, so if you have a store tuned well a few extra queries won't hurt.

Second, the database hit might not even be a problem.  The `shipping/rate_request` Model doesn't appear to be backed by a database.  If you look at the two times it's used in the core code

```
Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRatesByAddress
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::requestShippingRates
```

you can see the `shipping/rate_request` model is being instantiated, and then populated from already loaded fields.  Additionally, all the models used in `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate::collectRates` don't load anything from a database, they just do calculations.

It's admirable that you want to build something that's as performant as possible in the first go around, but there's too many complex interactions in a modern OO system to magically know the most performant way to do something.  Do what you need to to get the information you need, and handle performance tuning (if needed) during a maintenance release (or if you're not lucky enough to have maintenance release, when someone with power in your organization grumbles about the speed somewhere)

Third, when the system doesn't provide access to something yo need, that's what the class override system is for.  Something like

```
class Package_Module_Model_Carriertablerate extends
Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate
{
    public function getRate(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        $rate = parent::getRate($request);  
        Mage::register('package_module_carriertablerates', $rate);
        return $rate;
    }

}

...
//later, retrieve the rate
$rates = Mage::registry('package_module_carriertablerates');
```

You're basically calling the same code as before, but stowing the results away somewhere for later access. About as safe as an override can get.

Comment: Thanks Alan, great answer.  My concern about going back to the database was because this model seems not to go through the standard autoload process, hence why the `$model_load` event is not thrown.  I like the idea of using the `Mage::register` to store the value.  Does `Mage::register` store globally or just for that `checkout/session`?  IF it's global, then I'd need to check that the rate that is saved includes the `dest_zip` used to calculate it.  But that's an implementation detail.

Comment: P.S. The database load for `tablerate` is performed in `Mage_Shipping_Model_Mysql4_Carrier_Tablerate_Collection::__construct()` and is reasonably complex as it involves three tables in the join.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question.  I thought you wanted to grab it for use during the same request.  I'm pretty sure Mage::register is a per request thing .. global variables without violating global scope.  Also, FWIW, I just searched my local 1.4 and 1.4.1 codebase and didn't find the shipping_carrier_tablerate_load event anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I do want it on a per-request basis, so that's great.  Re the `shipping_carrier_tablerate_load` event, I was referring to the very handy generic `load_before` and `load_after` events per Joseph's blog post (http://masteringmagento.com/2010/06/events-list-in-magento-community-1-4/)