# Magento - Last event name that is executed after a page is loaded

Tags: events, magento, observer-pattern

In my custom module i have set a flag in session variable, and in `controller_action_layout_render_before` event, checking if the flag is set in then append a custom content.

I want to unset the flag in session variable after the page is loaded.

How can it be done.

Is there any event which is executed at the end when the page is getting loaded?

Answer (score 5):

The

```
controller_front_send_response_after
```

event should work for you.  Temporarily adding some logging to `app/Mage.php`

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{   
    //Mage::Log($name);                 
    file_put_contents('/tmp/event.log',"$name\n",FILE_APPEND);    

    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    #$result = self::registry('events')->dispatch($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

can get you a list of events that have fired for a particular request, which is usually enough to track down the event you're looking for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I've you're looking to store a variable only for the life of a single request, you might consider using Magento's registry.  Basically, you insert a value with `Mage::register('some_variable_name',$variable);` and retrieve it in some other context in the same request with `Mage::registry('some_variable_name');`

Refer to @Alan Storm's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848705/accessing-shipping-cost-in-magentos-cart-and-or-checkout/3851219#3851219) for more information.